# Send integer value using Broadcast receiver in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

How to pass a integer value from Service class using a Broadcast intent to a Activity. Below is my code but getting some errors,

Sending side

```
 private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {
        Log.d(TAG, "entered DisplayLoggingInfo");           
        int dataJNI = BioLIb.intFromJNI();    
        intent.putExtra("mykey", dataJNI);      
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Receiving side

```
private Intent intent;
```

the above is a global variable. In my onCreate I will call BroadcastReceiver class like below.

```
intent = new Intent(this, BroadCastService.class);
```

onReceive of BroadcastReceiver  i will call

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateUI(intent);       
       }
 int time = intent.getINtExtra("mykey", 1);
```

But I am not getting my exact value of `dataJNI` in a receiving side. I am always getting value is `1`,  How to get resolve this.

Comment: Print the value of dataJNI.

Comment: @Siddharth: Ya i will get integer value from my JNI class.

Comment: Your question is just so unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the intent that you received as a parameter of onReceive method

```
int time;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateUI(intent);   

            time = intent.getLongExtra("mykey", 1);    
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're sending you're putting an integer into the Intent Bundle. When receiving you0re trying to extract a long. Did you try using the same type in both sides?